# Magento Paypal issues with base currency INR

Tags: php, magento, paypal

Is there any way in Magento where I can integrate Paypal with base currency INR?
I have tried the following solutions

1) [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-checkout/magento-paypal-standard-how-to-pay-with-currency-other-than-base-one-and-do-it-in-your-language/)

2) [Magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency)

Comment: Magento does not support iNR As  base currency

Comment: The above comment is true. Anyway, there is an paid extension. [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-all-currencies.html). which might help you..

Answer (score 4):

From this [**Blog**](http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2013/12/paypal-payment-method-not-display-with.html):

> Go to **`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`**
>
> **Change this array:**
>
> `protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');`
>
> **To**
>
> `protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');`
>
> ### Another trick :
>
> Go to **`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php`**
>
> **Then change this function:**
>
> `public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
>   {
>       return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
>   }`
>
> **To**
>
> `public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
>   {
>       if($currencyCode == 'INR')
>       {
>           $currencyCode = 'USD';
>       }
>       return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
>   }`

I also found a paid extension, [MageOXY paypal all currencies](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-all-currencies.html) which assuring to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this really a solution? This will convert currency not the amount.

Answer (score 0):

This **FREE** Magento Extension that supports PayPal payments for not supported currencies by PayPal might be helpful for you.

https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

**Detailed answer here:** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79071/paypal-express-checkout-for-aed-currency