# Magento paypal express checkout issue for base currency INR

Tags: php, magento, paypal, currency, express-checkout

I have configured Paypal `express checkout` in Magento, It works fine when I set USD as a base currency , but as we know Paypal does not accept payment with INR currency code ,then it throws exception that 'currency not supported'

I have to set base currency as INR, has anyone been faced with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Also to convert INR currency value and show USD amount in Paypal follow below step.

Open app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Standard/Redirect.php

Search for:

```
foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {

$form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));

}
```

Replace with:

```
foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
if($field == 'amount_1'):
$from = 'INR';
$to = 'USD';
$price = $value;
$newPrice = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to),2);
$form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$newPrice));
elseif($field == 'amount_2'):
$from = 'INR';
$to = 'USD';
$price = $value;
$newPrice = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to),2);
$form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$newPrice));
else:
       $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
endif;
   }
```

That's it save and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to fix issue with INR and its conversion to USD when customer redirects to paypal. See **[here](http://www.magecoders.com/magento-extensions/paypal-multicurrency-extension)**

Answer (score -1):

check this question here [Magento Paypal issues with base currency INR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916361/magento-paypal-issues-with-base-currency-inr)

Plugin available http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-all-currencies.html

OR check this article on magento commerce http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

OR go to this blog for answer http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2013/12/paypal-payment-method-not-display-with.html

**Code**

```
Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Change this array
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');

To

protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');

Another trick :

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php

Then change this function

public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }

To

public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
   if($currencyCode == 'INR')
{
$currencyCode = 'USD';
}
return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
    }
```

Comment: I am using paypal express checkout and not paypal standard, so this is not working for me

Comment: This is not a fix and a proper solution. you are just converting the currency not the amount.