# Magento Paypal checkout with INR currency

Tags: magento

I have try all way from this site but still i'm get "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)." when base currency is "Indian Rupee" and checkout with paypal.

Without any extension is it posible ? if yes than plz tell me how ?

Comment: Here is the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916361/magento-paypal-issues-with-base-currency-inr/38344687#38344687

Answer (score 0):

For paypal checkout You must set base currency which paypal accept. paypal accept five currencies. you need to set base currency "USD" then try it.